# Convert numeric to character using looping

Tags: loops, character, numeric, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to familiarize and practice more about Microsoft Visual FoxPro. Can you help me convert numeric to character? What is the code (using some loops), for me to be able to study it more? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a loop to convert from numeric to character in VFP. You use a function. The simplest is TRANSFORM(), but depending exactly what you need, you might use STR() or one of the PADx() functions (PADL(), PADC(), PADR()).

For example, if you have a variable nNum with a value of 25000, you can do any of the following:

```
TRANSFORM(m.nNum) && "25000"
STR(m.nNum, 10) && "     25000"
PADL(m.nNum, 7) && "  25000"
```

etc.

Comment: Also `CAST(m.nnum as Character(5))`